# Rails application using Rmagick, function from_blob fails with NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat after ImageMagick update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

I have an application running on rails 1.9.3 and recently my server was updated and installed a new version of ImageMagick(v 6.8.0-7).

After this my application started throwing an exception when Magick::Image.from_blob() is called:

"Magick::ImageMagickError (NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/361):"

I updated Rmagick to the latest gem version(2.13.2) but it did not solve the problem

does anybody ran into the same problem! On the log of what changed in ImageMagick there is nothing related to this and neither on Rmagick!

If you have any clue please help!

all the best,

Andre

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick can be compiled with certain flags for e.g. TIFF or JPEG support. Maybe the support for certain file types was moved into separate packages that you'll need to install now?

If this is the case, you'll probably need to recompile the rmagick gem after installing.

Comment: after all just had to reinstall the gem again and restart the server... tried almost everything! sorry for not replying to the thread sooner